# Where is the location of WordPress default CSS for front-end?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Where is the location of WordPress default CSS for front-end? I am not able to find it in w_head function. I want to add CSS directly into the page between style tags and don't want to call CSS.

Comment: why  are you unvoted this question ??

Comment: Can you share link to website, every theme has different location of css file

Comment: I know the location sir, but i want to find out where is the including path in wp_head function ... because i want to directly print the css in between style tags

Comment: Wordpress includes file with name "style.css" from theme folder You should empty the style.css file and dump its content in hearder file

Comment: Its also adding  bootstrap css also..... how to print that

Comment: Such details vary from theme to theme. It can only be found after looking at files.

Comment: do you have any mail id so i can drop you mail there about link of the site

Comment: Yes about.me/ximrx